# Python Unicode Normalization Can Not Normalize '\u0069\u0307' (i̇)

Tags: python, unicode, python-unicode, unicode-normalization

I'm working with Python's unicodedata module to normalize strings, but I'm encountering an unexpected behavior with a particular character. My goal is to normalize a string containing the character "i̇" (a Latin small letter i with dot above, Unicode U+0069 U+0307) using different normalization forms provided by unicodedata.

Here's the code snippet I'm using:

```
import unicodedata

test_string = "i̇"
print("Original length:", len(test_string))
print("NFKC normalized length:", len(unicodedata.normalize('NFKC', test_string)))
print("NFD normalized length:", len(unicodedata.normalize('NFD', test_string)))
print("NFC normalized length:", len(unicodedata.normalize('NFC', test_string)))
print("NFKD normalized length:", len(unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', test_string)))
```

The output I'm getting is:

```
Original length: 2
NFKC normalized length: 2
NFD normalized length: 2
NFC normalized length: 2
NFKD normalized length: 2
```

I expected the length of the normalized string to change with different normalization forms, especially with NFD and NFKD, which typically decompose characters. However, the length remains unchanged in all normalization forms.

Can anyone explain why this specific character does not change in length after normalization? Is there a different approach I should take to normalize such characters in Python?

Comment: What it your expected output?

Comment: I except "i like" character with 1 length

Comment: my aim is i want to remove accents in string so i am iterating over string and check. but with two length characters my accent check does not work properly.

Comment: Not all Unicode character sequences can be combined. If you want to remove accents, you need the long form, and then you remove the "combining" part

Comment: Is this perhaps confusion coming from a Turkish background? U+0069 is the Latin Small Letter `i`, which already includes the dot. It makes no sense to combine that with U+0307 Combining Dot Above.

Comment: Now i understand folks, U+0069 and U+0307 should not be combined. i will find a way to use  unicodedata library for remove non-ascii words and keep the Turkish letters.

Comment: @VeliEroglu U+0069 and U+0307 are normalised, it is valid NFC, NFD, NFKC and NFKD. There is no precomposed form.  For Turkish and Azeri __İ__, language insensitive lowercasing and also casefolding will give you U+0069 U+0307, Turkish and Azerii sensitive casing will just give you U+0069. If data is Turkish, then its been lowercased using non-Turkish rules. Lowercasing __Í__ (U+00CD) will give U+00ED. But for Lithuanian you should get U+0069 U+0307 U+0301. Note that python casing is language invariant or insensitive so for Turkish data it is common to find U+0069 U+0307.

Comment: @MSalters it will be found in Turkish data manipulated and cased using Python. It can also be found in Lithuanian data when a lowercase i needs a diacritic, when Lithuanian i has a diacritic it retains the dot, this is achieved in Unicode by including the combining dot above.

Comment: Great Explanation, Thanks @MSalters

Comment: @Andj: "diacritics" are a class of marks, e.g. `í` and `ì`. Those diacritics can indeed be expressed in Unicode with a combining character. But `U+0307` is specifically the "dot above", not a `\`` or `'` diacritic.

Comment: @MSalters, I know that non-spacing marks are, and aren't. I know U+0307 is a dot above. See https://unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/SpecialCasing.txt : "Lithuanian retains the dot in a lowercase i when followed by accents. Remove DOT ABOVE after "i" with upper or titlecase. Introduce an explicit dot above when lowercasing capital I's and J's whenever there are more accents above. (of the accents used in Lithuanian: grave, acute, tilde above, and ogonek)"

Comment: @MSalters casing data for Lithuanian includes: `00CD; 0069 0307 0301; 00CD; 00CD; lt; # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER I WITH ACUTE` SO for Lithuanian Lowercase version of U+00CD is U+0069 U+0307 U+0301.

Comment: @MSalters In https://unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/CaseFolding.txt, the casefolding for U+0130 is `0130; T; 0069; # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER I WITH DOT ABOVE` this is a special rule when casefolding is tailored, which rarely occurs and you can't do in Python. Full casefolding uses the rule `0130; F; 0069 0307; # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER I WITH DOT ABOVE`, so U+0130 is folded to U+0069 U+0307.

Comment: Special casing has the unconditional mapping (i.e. language insensitive or default mapping of: 0130; 0069 0307; 0130; 0130; # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER I WITH DOT ABOVE. For Turkish and Azeri, you have the tailorings: `0130; 0069; 0130; 0130; tr; # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER I WITH DOT ABOVE` and 
`0130; 0069; 0130; 0130; az; # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER I WITH DOT ABOVE`. There are also additional tailorings for NFD data, etc.